# How to submit form automatically after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I want to submit form automatically after x seconds without pressing the submit button. [This sample](https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/NxQ4A/) runs fine, but when I put this sample in [my code](http://jsbin.com/ceyanebepa/edit?html,js,output), it did't work.

What's wrong with my code?

```
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
    CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.anyword); 
};


var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-stsrc",
    indentUnit: 4,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    highlightSelectionMatches: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    extraKeys: {
        "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete" ,
        "Ctrl-Space":function(cm){  CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.anyword); }, 
        "'.'" : function(cmm){ CodeMirror.showHint(cmm, CodeMirror.hint.anyword);},
    },
    autohint: true,
    readOnly: false,
    lineWrapping: true,
}); 

editor.on("blur", function(codeMirror) { codeMirror.save(); });

editor.refresh();

var orig = CodeMirror.hint.anyword;

CodeMirror.hint.anyword = function(cm) {
    var inner = orig(cm) || { from: cm.getCursor(), to: cm.getCursor(),  list: []};
    inner.list.push("mariano");
    inner.list.push("florencia");
    inner.list.push("zoe");

    return inner;
};
var timeoutId;
$('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Textarea Change');

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
        saveToDB();
    }, 1000);
});

function saveToDB()
{
    console.log('Saving to the db');
    form = $('.contact-form');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            $('.form-status-holder').html('Saving...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // You can get data returned from your ajax call here. ex. jqObj.find('.returned-data').html()
            // Now show them we saved and when we did
            var d = new Date();
            $('.form-status-holder').html('Saved! Last: ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());
        },
    });
}

// This is just so we don't go anywhere  
// and still save if you submit the form
$('.contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    saveToDB();
    e.preventDefault();
});

CodeMirror.hint.anyword = function(cmm) {
    var inner1 = orig(cmm) || { from: cmm.getCursor(), to: cmm.getCursor(),  list: []};
    inner1.list.push("one");
    inner1.list.push("tow");
    inner1.list.push("three");

    return inner1;
};
```

EDIT :
the problem solved by this change :

```
var timeoutId;
$('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Textarea Change');
    //alert("chang Comment!");

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
        document.forms["contact-form"].submit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: you can use setTimeout() function for that????

Comment: Can you try to correct my wrong ?... I don't knew what wrong in my try... you can correct and put the link of correct code @Rafi

Comment: In your code you are not loading jQuery, I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: First of all - your code uses jQuery. in jsFiddle you have added jquery framework while in jsbin you have not.

Comment: Ok , after add it work ??

Comment: works fine after you add jQuery.

Comment: Can give me the link of correct code plz

Comment: Dear sara, if you dont know how to add jquery to your code, i strongly recommend learning javascript from the beginning instead of messing around with code blocks that you do not understand.

Comment: I add jquery to my code but it did't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the `editor` `change` event:-

```
editor.on('change', function() {
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vaqarafika/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: open the console (F12) and you will see `Textarea Change` then `Saving to the db`. which are your logs your code.

Comment: Ok it run , but why I must to open consol to show the result?

Comment: When I put it into my code on eclipse  and then the code not do submit never

Answer (score 1):

First : thanks for every body answer me
second : the problem solved only by add :

```
document.forms["id-form"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery in your fiddle. If you open console in your fiddle. you can see the error message

```
ceyanebepa.js:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Include Jquery and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Ok thanks , but can give me the link of coorect code after run ?

Comment: You can check now. @sara I have just added the script of jquery at the end of the body in your code.

Comment: ok I add it can you see it now it not work  http://jsbin.com/putilaweti/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Did it worked for you?? are you getting your expected answer.

Comment: welcome. Dont forget to give a up vote if it is helped :)

Comment: I press true for your answer :) @Rafi Ud Daula Refat